# как задать выполнение функции в течении определённого времени?

Tags: c#, unity3d

есть кнопка и когда на неё нажимаешь начинает выполняться функция, и как сделать так что-бы функция выполнялась в течении времени?

Comment: Task.Wait, например. Там есть перегрузка с фиксированным ожиданием по времени, но результата можно и не дождаться... Task t = Task.Run( () => {DoSomething();});  TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(150); if (! t.Wait(ts)) Console.WriteLine("The timeout interval elapsed."); Прям из msdn. Смотря, что требуется. ТЗ какое-то расплывчатое.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Manual/Coroutines](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/2019.4/Manual/Coroutines.html)

```
private IEnumerator _sometnig;

public void DoSomething (float time)
{
    _sometnig = SometnigCoroutine(time);
    StartCoroutine(_sometnig);
}

public void StopSomething ()
{
    StopCoroutine(_sometnig);
}

private IEnumerator SometnigCoroutine (float time)
{
    float Timer = 0;
    while (Timer < time)
    {
        yield return null; // wait new frame
        Timer += Time.deltaTime;
        Debug.Log("I am fine "+Mathf.FloorToInt(time/Timer*100f)+"%");
    }
    Debug.Log("Iol, i finished =(");
}
```